# Python .1 - .1 = extremely small number w/negative exponent?

Tags: math, python-2.7

This has got to be a well-traveled gotcha of some sort. Define the following function `foo()`:

```
>>> def foo():
...     x = 1
...     while x != 0:
...             x -= .1
...             if x < 0:
...                     x = 0
...             print x
```

So of course, when we call the function, we get exactly what we expect to get.

```
>>> foo()
0.9
0.8
0.7
0.6
0.5
0.4
0.3
0.2
0.1
1.38777878078e-16    # O_o
0
```

So, I know that math with integers vs. floating point numbers can get a little weird. Just typing `3 - 2.9` yields such an answer:

```
>>> 3 - 2.9
0.10000000000000009
```

So, in fairness -- this is not causing an issue in the script I'm mucking about with. But surely this creeps up and bites people who would actually be affected by values as astronomically small as `1.38777878078e-16`. And in order to prevent there from ever being an issue because of the strangely small number, I've got this gem sitting at the bottom of my controller du jour:

```
if (x < .1 and x > 0) or x < 0:
    x = 0
```

That can't be the solution... unless it totally *is*. So... *is* it? If not, what's the trick here?

Comment: No that's not negative... there's no negative sign _in the front_ of the number. It's an "extremely small number" (practically 0) then you subtracted `0.1`...

Comment: UGH. I knew that too. That's a lousy title I've given my question. Negative number != negative exponent

Comment: Perhaps use http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html - quoted from that page: `"In decimal floating point, 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3 is exactly equal to zero. In binary floating point, the result is 5.5511151231257827e-017."`

Comment: https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf

Comment: Just like the fraction `1/3` can't be represented exactly as a decimal number, the fraction `1/10` cannot be represented exactly as a binary number -- they are both infinitely repeating.  So, if you naively add up a fixed number of digits, your results will likely be inexact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can certainly "creep up and bite people", generally when they try to compare floats:

```
>>> a = 1 / 10
>>> b = 0.6 - 0.5
>>> a == b
False
```

Therefore it is common to compare floats using a tolerance:

```
>>> tolerance = 0.000001
>>> abs(a - b) < tolerance
True
```

Answer (score 0):

This program:

```
def foo():
    x = 1
    while x != 0:
        x -= .1
        if x < 0:
            x = 0
        print '%.20f' % x
foo()
```

prints out this:

```
0.90000000000000002220
0.80000000000000004441
0.70000000000000006661
0.60000000000000008882
0.50000000000000011102
0.40000000000000013323
0.30000000000000015543
0.20000000000000014988
0.10000000000000014433
0.00000000000000013878
0.00000000000000000000
```

You were not printing the numbers out with enough precision to see what was actually going on.  Compare this with the output of `print '%.20f' % x` when you explicitly set `x` to `0.9` and `0.8` and so forth.  You may want to pay particular attention to the result for `0.5`.

Answer (score -1):

You miss the point - that isn't something you want to have a workaround for. Just trust VM, and assume, that it does all the computations as they should be done.

What you want to do, is to format your number. Spot the difference between value, and its representation.

```
>>> x = 0.9
>>> while x>0.1:
...     x -= 0.1
... 
>>> x
1.3877787807814457e-16
>>> "{:.2f}".format(x)
'0.00'
```

Here you have example of showing you value with 2 decimal points. More on formatting (number formatting too) you'll find [HERE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting)

Comment: If you "assume that it does all the computations as they should be done", you are living in a state of sin; floating point numbers ARE NOT REALS, and treating them as reals will lead to poor precision and problems such as these. You must understand how float's are implemented in order to write competent code that uses them. This is exactly the wrong piece of advice.

Comment: I get the sentiment that "the computer isn't screwing up; you are" -- but I don't know that I'm hip to the notion that I'm suppose to implicitly trust everything Computer says to do.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect that. Did I say, that it did any computations on REAL numbers? You've got exactly correct answer for what you asked - you explicitly used floats, so you got float result after float operations. Understand what are you doing, and assume that in that domain those calculations are correct - this is what I meant. Computer isn't screwing you - he is totally noncreative genius, he will answer according to his best knowledge. You are screwing yourself, when you're talking its language without understanding it.

Comment: Also, I find it ugly, trying to "fix" the result, just because you expect some value. Computer did it's work, it's your thing to show those results to user in readable form. Now I think I explained my thoughts clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for showing me that the last thing in the world I actually wanted was a function that subtracted 0.1 from 1 until it got 0 and stopped. This changes my whole perspective. I'm refactoring all my code to correctly expect 1.38777878078e-16 in 0's place. In everything. Forever.

Comment: Again, trusting that the VM did the correct computations means not understanding how they work, and almost certainly getting far less precision than if you worked more defensively.